# Data truncation: Data too long for column 'processed' at row 1 even after disabling strict mode

Tags: mysql

I'm getting UPDATE billing2.fct_calls SET processed = 'false': Data truncation: Data too long for column 'processed' at row 1, even after disabling strict mode.

This is what my db shows from another connection, while im getting the error above from connections made by an application:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What data type are you using for processed field?

Comment: BIT(1), but as I said in another comment, I know the root cause of the problem, still I have to make run without modifying the application that executes the update if possible.

Comment: so your query should be UPDATE billing2.fct_calls SET processed = 0, plus you can type cast ex (int)$_POST['XXX'] to prevent errors

Answer (score 0):

Could be you are using  string instead of boolean

try  using

```
UPDATE billing2.fct_calls SET processed = false
```

and if you need to disable strict mode  with the

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

remember to restart the dbengine

Comment: I know the cause of the problem and it will be fixed but for now I have to get it running without a fix is there a way to allow it to run on mysql (5.7.11) , I don't care about the actual value being set anyways.

Comment: Well  .. have you restarted the db engine ... i have update the answer with this suggestion too